# Jquery multiple autocomplete field

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I have the jquery auto complete from the jquery website. it is working just fine for one field. However now I want to add different field with different values in it, how do I do this? I have tried couple of ways but screwed up the whole system. Over all one of my fields is working one doesnt now. do I need to give it a new function name. I am new at this things.

I thought by adding a new field and new var on top it would work but it didng

```
var projects = [
  {
    value: "CMPT101",
    label: "CMPT 101",
    desc: "Discrete Mathematics I"

  },


  var instr={
      value:"johnson "
      lable:"Johnson"
  }
]



select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#instr" ).val( ui.item.label );
        $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
        $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
        $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6wTHK/4/

Comment: there are several typing errors in your fiddle ^^ can't work!

Comment: you are missing a `{` in your fiddle at `JavaScript line 65`. You also need to include `jQuery` and `jQuery UI`

Comment: also ID unique violation in your input fields. they cant have the same id.

Comment: Sorry about that guys. okay its been fixed now thanks but how do I get the second field to become a drop box, with tottaly different values?

Comment: fill a second `var foo =[{ yikes:'super' }, ..]` and also give all jquery things behind like in the first one.

Comment: @codelio do you mean id of searchbox? is int that from css and I can reuse it ?

Comment: @benzo your inputs have 2 IDs

Comment: just remember, never use `id` in one tag twice and never use id namespaces twice.. your idear of doing autocomplete twice is nice, but like this code is written you should `code` the same as you did with the first autocomplete a second time. otherwise you would have to fiddle with the problems you get by mixing.. if you understand how this works, you can figure out how to shorten your code i think.. sun is shining! :)

Comment: lol @codelio nothing is shining yet, let me try and see what I can do ... but I thought you can use Id as many times as you want but not class

Comment: id means identity so its unique, and the most js (even jQuery) and DOM interpreter think after finding the first ID thats it. But class you can use and add as much as you want an as often you want.
this kind of misstyping you find out easy with http://validator.w3.org/ also jsfiddle has build-in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did an example to explain to you what you need to do to make more inputs.

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/6wTHK/6/ ***not*** as in the code below

Lets say we have two `inputs` :

```
<input  name="project1" id="searchbox1" placeholder="Cmpt 1"/>
<input  name="project2" id="searchbox2" placeholder="Cmpt 2"/>
```

**`#searchbox1` has it's values saved in the `var projects1`**

```
var projects1 = [
      {
        value: "CMPT101",
        label: "CMPT 101",
        desc: "Discrete Mathematics I"
},
{
        value: "CMPT102",
        label: "CMPT 102",
        desc: "Discrete Mathematics II"
},
{
        value: "CMPT103",
        label: "CMPT 103",
        desc: "Discrete Mathematics III"
}];
```

**`#searchbox2` has it's values saved in the `var projects2`**

```
var projects2 = [
          {
            value: "CMPT104",
            label: "CMPT 105",
            desc: "Discrete Mathematics IV"
    },
    {
            value: "CMPT106",
            label: "CMPT 106",
            desc: "Discrete Mathematics V"
    },
    {
            value: "CMPT107",
            label: "CMPT 107",
            desc: "Discrete Mathematics VI"
    }];
```

**Now for each `input` we add the `.autocomplete()` function;**

```
 $( "#searchbox1" ).autocomplete({ //change #searchbox2 to your input id
      minLength: 0,
      source: projects1, //change here the source of your values
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#searchbox1" ).val( ui.item.label );
        //you had more stuff here
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#searchbox1" ).val( ui.item.label );
        //you had more stuff here
        return false;
      }, 
      })
    .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
      return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
    };
```

**And for the second `input`**

```
$( "#searchbox2" ).autocomplete({ //change #searchbox2 to your input id
          minLength: 0,
          source: project2, //change here the source of your values
          focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#searchbox2" ).val( ui.item.label );
            //you had more stuff here
            return false;
          },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#searchbox2" ).val( ui.item.label );
            //you had more stuff here
            return false;
          }, 
          })
        .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li>" )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
        };
```

Comment: okay thank you so much, let me try this now, bc I did it once but maybe I missed stuff

Comment: Is it okay if I say I love you here ??? thank you so much, I wish I knew as much as you did

Comment: i think thats what stackOVERflow means. there are a lot of rude dudes also. but one day they need help :))

Comment: is it possible to make height of the drop box certain, so you have to scroll down to see more

Comment: @codelio is it possible to make height of the drop box certain, so you have to scroll down to see more ?

Comment: add to your css `.ui-autocomplete{height:200px;overflow-y:scroll;}` and change the `height` to as much as you want.